# Is there a shortcut to move currently active application to workspace x in cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

Is there any way to move the currently active window to another workspace? For example, if Firefox is currently active and I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then Firefox would get moved to workspace 2, like in i3 window manager.

I know it can be done with dragging but I would need to shortcut it. In the settings, I could only find the option to switch workspaces and not to move applications on them, though I could have missed it. I know this question was probably asked many times, but I just cannot find the answer.

**I am using Linux Mint 20 with Cinnamon 4.6.7**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to Settings => Keyboard => Shortcuts:

[image: screenshot showing the relevant section of the Cinnamon Settings tool]

Once there, select "inter-workspace" from the list on the left and you should be able to set the shortcut you're after:

[image: screenshot showing the relevant section of the Cinnamon Settings tool]

Comment: Yes, thank you this worked, I was a moron for not looking into the "Windows" subcategory